# Remove dynamically added input file IE8

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-8, jquery-selectors

I'm trying to remove a dinamically added `input type file` using **jquery.1.9.1** on IE8. This `input` is added inside a hidden `form` by cloning the original one.

**Reference** for the cloning to upload files using IFrame: [Hacking a File API onto IE8](http://blog.filepicker.io/post/33906205133/hacking-a-file-api-onto-ie8)

```
// Where file.value is an arbitrary string
var input = $('#formupload input[data-file="' + file.value + '"]');

//does nothing, the element still inside the HTML document
input.remove();
```

When I log or alert the result from the selector returns `object`.

What am I missing here? This is only for IE8, for file upload, for other browsers I'm driven in another direction.

Comment: Did you try a selector that doesn't use HTML5 data attributes ?

Comment: "object" tells you nothing, if the selector returns nothing, it is still object since it is an jQuery object. An object is returning so chaining still works! Inspect the object or check the length `console.log(input.length);`

Comment: @adeneo I did using the name, but still the same.

Comment: As @epascarello mentioned, the way to know if an element is returned is to check the selectors length, not it's type.

Comment: @epascarello So, Is there something wrong with the selector? It's working when i tried it in another browser... anything specific for IE?

Comment: @adeneo The selector length returns 0, so what can I do for IE8?

Comment: Use a selector that works ?

Comment: What does `console.log(file.value)` show?  Are you sure there's a element with its `data-file` attribute equal to that?

Comment: What does `alert($("[id=formupload]").length)` give you?

Comment: I solve the issue only changing the selector for a class selector! Thank you all!

Answer (score -1):

You cannot clear a file input. You have to remove it and reiniitiate it.